# How to assign author ID and Paper ID to relations table?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am having trouble with my project as you know an author can have a multiple papers and a paper can have multiple authors. Since is a many to many relation ship I design my database like so
[image: Authors Table]

[image: Papers Table]

[image: Relations Table]

I am confused on how will I input a Title then Authors and relate them for display and citations
do you guys have any ideas? I am using Laravel 9 in making this project

Here is the source code that I did
Create Title of the Paper then routes back to index

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<form action="{{ route('papers.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
  
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Title:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</form>

@endsection
```

Papers Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $paper = new Papers();

        $paper->title = $request->title;

        $paper->save();

        return redirect()->route('papers.index');
    }
```

index blade

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Debugging</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('papers.create') }}"> Create New Paper</a>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>


@foreach($paper as $papers)

{{$papers->title}}

<div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('AddAuthor',$papers->PaperID) }}"> Add Author(s)</a>
            </div>

@endforeach

@endsection
```

Authors blade

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<form action="{{ route('authors.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
  
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>First Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="Fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Last Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="Lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</form>

@endsection
```

Authors Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $relate = DB::table('papers')
            ->where('PaperID', '=', $request->paper_ID)
            ->value('PaperID');

        $author = new Authors();
        $relations = new Relate();

        $author->Fname = $request->Fname;
        $author->Lname = $request->Lname;

        $relations->paper_ID = $relate;

        $author->save();
        $relations->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: Please share with us what have tried so far. Also it would be easier for you to do relation assignment if you don't rename the `'id'` column. I would highly suggest you to refactor your table `papers` and rename `PaperID` to `id`

Comment: As you are using Laravel 9 for you project have a look at the introduction for [Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
If you have not already tried something. If you tried something and you failed somewhere, share the code and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: So what I tried is that users input the title first then gets redirected back to the index page there they can add an author and gets routed to the author create page and that's where I got stuck I'll edit the question so that people can see the codes

Comment: Please post the relevant relation definition of the two models, too

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to have a look at the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships explaining how to set up relationships between Models.

Once you have defined relationships inside your Models you then will be able to save relationships easily without even having to care about the paper_id (it will be handle by Eloquent for you).

Comment: Hi @gaetan-hexadog - "to look up documentation" and sharing the link is not a good answer to a question. And was already commented on under the question.